# What is the new phpMyID?

Tags: openid

phpMyID is deprecated. Is there another option? I'd like to authenticate just one user on my site as simply as possible, but I don't want to use delegation.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no real reason you can't keep using phpMyID.

That said, http://wiki.openid.net/w/page/12995226/Run-your-own-identity-server

Comment: phpMyId apparently broke with the php 5.2 or 5.3 so, at least at the moment, I can't keep using phpMyId :-(

Comment: Yes, phpMyID uses `session_is_registered()` which has been removed as of PHP 5.4.0.

Comment: FYI: I got phpMyID working in php v5.5.3 by replacing `session_is_registered('blah')` with `isset($_SESSION['blah'])` - there's only 3 occurrences to replace in `MyID.php`.